# How to use SAML in Liferay Community Edition for SSO Integration?

Tags: liferay, single-sign-on, saml, liferay-7, liferay-ide

I am using Liferay Community edition. I want to use SAML for SSO integration. It looks like SAML is available only for Liferay Enterprise edtion. Can someone suggest me how to use SAML as sso integration in Liferay Community Edition?

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly state: the existing SAML plugin implementation is for EE. You'll have to implement your own in order to use it with CE. When you have finished it, you might want to publish it on marketplace

In a related note, using SAML might point to the scenario in which you're using Liferay. And typically usecases for SAML are rather enterprisey.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Can you please tell me, what are the ways to implement our own SAML in Liferay CE?

Comment: Is SiteMinder available for Liferay CE?